# subprocess call error, invalid application

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

So i am running into a problem using subprocess.call() and i think i may just be calling it wrong. I am using:

```
subprocess.call('testingosfile.py')
```

and i get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.call('testingosfile.py')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

and the contents of `testingosfile.py` is:

```
print "hello world!"
raw_input('....')
```

how do i manage to get this running?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message makes perfect sense - with `subprocess`, you can only start an executable.  So, to fix it, you should start an executable.  Specifically, you should start the Python interpreter and tell it to run your script.  Something like

```
subprocess.call(['python.exe', 'testingosfile.py'])
```

should work, although you might have to provide the full path to the Python interpreter (I can't test at the moment).

However, have you considered importing `testingosfile.py` instead?  Whenever you import a Python script, all the commands in that script are run.  Using

```
import testingosfile
```

inside a function in order to execute the commands would be poor style, but you could package up the useful commands of `testingosfile.py` into some function.  Then, you could use

```
import testingosfile
```

at the top of your main script, and just call that function whenever you want to print Hello World and get the user's input.

Comment: Great! it works! :D (although you would indeed have to provide the full path to the interpreter if you dont have it in your `PATH`) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try subprocess.call("myfile.ext", shell=True)